# Django how to use the ``receiver`` decorator on a class instead on a function

Tags: python, django

Using Django signals `receiver` decorator I have the following function.

```
@receiver(post_save)
def action_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    pass
```

**Is it possible to use the `receiver` decorator on a class instead on a function?** The reason for this is I would like to have a `__init__` method etc.

i.e. How can I get something like this to work...

```
class ActionSignals

    def __init__(self):
        self.stuff

    @receiver(post_save)
    def action_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        print(self.stuff)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the `receiver` decorator on a class method doesn't really make sense. When do you expect the object to be instantiated and the `__init__` method to run?

You can use the manual method for [connecting signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions), instead of the `receiver` decorator.

First instantiate the object:

```
action_signal = ActionSignals()
```

Then you can use the `connect` method to connect the signal:

```
post_save.connect(action_signal.action_signal)
```

Comment: I could use ``AppConfig`` to to init the object?

Comment: Yes, initialising the object and connecting the signal in the app config's `ready()` method sounds good.

Answer (score 7):

#### Adding a class-based signal handler

You can do this:

```
class ActionSignals(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...            

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.stuff)
```

Then to connect the signal handler:

```
handler = ActionSignals()

post_save.connect(handler)
```

This makes use of python's "magic" [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method that allows you to use an instance of a class as a function.

#### Avoiding duplicates

Be careful about where you are adding the handlers in your code, as you might create duplicates. For example if you were to put the second bit of code in the module root, it would add a handler every time the module is imported.

To avoid this you can do the [following](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals):

```
post_save.connect(handler, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
```

As @Alasdair pointed out, you can add handlers in `AppConfig.ready()` (and this is the recommended place to do it), although generally it can be done anywhere if you take care not to create undesired duplicates.

See ["Where should this code live?" in this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions).

Comment: If using the `@receiver` decorator, how do you specify a `dispatch_uid`?

Comment: This is probably useless for @AdamParkin after all this time but maybe it will help others: from looking at the code, it seems you can pass the same parameters to the decorator because it will pass them untouched to signal.connect(). Look in `django/dispatch/dispatcher.py`, lines [288](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f425835cbec603888ffb461ec0f54ef191ace849/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py#L288) and [290](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f425835cbec603888ffb461ec0f54ef191ace849/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py#L290) (for Django 3.0).