# I'm using django signals to get logged in user, but I'm having error saying "Signal receivers must be callable." I had made receiver though

Tags: python, django

In `views.py` I'm simply creating objects of Message class and did other stuff

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+',  blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='logged_in_user', blank=True, null=True)
    form_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+',  blank=True, null=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.message 

    @staticmethod
    def get_conversations(user):
        conversations = Message.objects.filter(user=user).values('conversation').annotate(
            last=Max('date')).order_by('-last')
        users = []
        for conversation in conversations:
            users.append({
                'user': User.objects.get(pk=conversation['conversation']),
                'last': conversation['last'],
                'status': 'online' if hasattr(conversation, 'logged_in_user') else 'offline',
            })
        return users


    def login_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        Message(conversation=user).save()


    def logout_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        try:
            u = Message.objects.get(conversation=user)
            u.delete()
        except Message.conversation.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    user_logged_in.connect(login_user)
    user_logged_out.connect(logout_user)
```

Using django signals to get logged in user in a different way was quite easy and code worked in my project, but here I want to implement in different way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django how to use the \`\`receiver\`\` decorator on a class instead on a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124723/django-how-to-use-the-receiver-decorator-on-a-class-instead-on-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

umm.. you can try channels for message purpose 
if you have any query you can get all the stuff from
[here][1] 
https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django