# Is it possible to register an instance method as a Signal receiver via decorators?

Tags: python, django, decorator, django-signals

There are multiple ways to register class methods as Signal receivers in Django. Using the built-in `receiver` decorator is an obvious solution, but can work only with static methods or simple functions:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class SignalCollection:
    @receiver(post_save)
    def some_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        # code
        pass
```

With instance methods, this decorator won't work as such methods require `self` as a first parameter. In this case, instantiating after defintion is what works:

```
class SignalCollection:
    def some_signal_a(self, sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        # code
        pass

    def some_signal_b(self, sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        # code
        pass

collection = SignalCollection()

post_save.connect(collection.some_signal_a)
post_save.connect(collection.some_signal_b)
```

The potential issue with this is that it's not well encapsulated, and in case of many methods contains a lot of repeation.

For solving this issue, I intended to apply custom decorators. My question is: is it possible to create such a decorator, either for the class itself, or for its methods, that can perform connections without instantiating the class?

My research yielded no results, and many of my attempts were failed - adding `receiver` through `method_decorator` can work, but in none of my snippets were the signals triggered, meaning the connection did not happen.

Creating a class decorator that decorates all its methods seemed promising:

```
def signal_collection(target_class):
    def _is_acceptable_callable(func):
        return (inspect.ismethod(func) or inspect.isfunction(func)) and not inspect.isbuiltin(func)

    for name, target_method in inspect.getmembers(target_class):
        if not _is_acceptable_callable(target_method):
            continue

        decorated_method = some_extra_decorator(target_method)

        setattr(target_class, name, decorated_method)
        
    return target_class

@signal_collection
class SignalCollection:
    def some_signal(self, sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        pass
```

The advantage of this pattern is that you can easily modify `signal_collection` to contain wrappers, and then use args and kwargs as inputs similar to the function-based `receiver` (that is, specifying signal, sender, etc), but still, no such `some_extra_decorator` could I make that would run without explicitly calling `<signal>.connect`.

I can't be exactly sure but my theory is that it's not possible at all. [A fragment of a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33124941/2320153) suggests that Signals can't be connected arbitrarily on this level.

It has to do something with the fact that Signals should be loaded explicitly in AppConfig.ready, similar to the way Models are registered to Sites.

I'm not confident enough about it, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. `method_decorator` won't work on signal receivers. They are designed to decorate methods accessed by their instance name. It can be customized to work with signal receivers but I don't think it's worth the effort. I switched to regular functions

Comment: Yes, sadly I got the answer later on that by the fundamental nature of decorators (= they are mostly only syntactic sugar), it's not possible. I may write my own answer when I have the time.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt, any progress on this topic? I don't like having signals as separate function in model module. Please, share your experience, if such.

Comment: @Nicko no, I decided for a different solution. As I said, most likely you can't do it. The best I can suggest is to have a `signals.py` file in your appropriate modules and list all your functions there.